# How to use activity indicator in tabbar controller while switching tab item

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, nsthread, uiactivityindicatorview

I am using tab bar controller in my project.in each class's viewWillAppear i am parsing some data it takes some time to load. i put activity indicator before parsing the data in viewWillAppear but it is not working..and also itried below code also that too not worked what to do?

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:    (UIViewController *)viewController
{
           [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadStartAnimating) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the solution of my issue... i called the parsing class in view will appear method that makes me the problem..instead of calling the parsing class in view will appear method i created one user defined method(GetData). In that method i called the parsing class. in view will appear i called the user defined method(GetData) by following code.

```
    [self performSelector:@selector(GetData) withObject:self afterDelay:1];
```